# WCF | Entity Framework | Json | Restful

Tags: c#, database, wcf, entity-framework

I was practicing on WCF. I had a database and I used Entity Framework to generate entities. I have two entities called `Film` and `Book`. I can do list/add/delete/update on Film/Book. But I think if I have more entities, I would repeat a lot of times of the same functions (list/add/delete/update). Now what I want to do is to write a general function using C# like:

```
public List<"name of the entity"> GetList(the name of the entity)
{
//do something
}
```

I've been working on it for 2 days and I didn't make it.

Please help me!

Comment: You want your method to return a compile-time static value (type of the entity) by passing a run-time value (the name of the entity class as string)? This won't work. You could return a non-generic version of `List` or simply `List<object>`, but you're not gonna have fun with it. You should refrain from using such error prone constructs.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. I spent two days already. I didn't have fun...But any ideas to avoid repeating the code? or maybe I should just repeating the code...

Comment: should this method be on the server side or in the client proxy?

Comment: I suppose it's on the server side.

Comment: @JustAnotherUser: I agree, this won't work: `public List<Person> GetList("Persons")` since you are missing the generic argument but having a generic GetList() method is possible `public List<Person> GetList<Person>()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called generic repository pattern: [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/entity-framework-generic-repository-pattern) or [here](http://jason-mitchell.com/software-development/data-access-using-a-generic-repository-in-c/), or [here](http://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/a-reference-architecture-part-5/).

But also note [this](http://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern). Personally I wouldn't call it an anti-pattern, just make sure you have a repository for each aggregate root and that you can overload any of them with custom data access methods next to the generic ones.